# Making CTRL+(mouse scroll) work with word 2007 for zooming?

Tags: mouse, microsoft-word-2007, zoom

I am using Word 2007 and am trying to use the combo:

Ctrl + mouse scroll

To zoom in and out of the doc.

This function works fine in other programs (like google-chrome)

Is there a place to fix this ?

edit: I found out that when I scroll the mouse FAST the desired effect happens.  I would like it to also work with slower scrolling.  The thing is also that on any other program - the scrolling acts as normal. (so this is not a system wide preference)

Comment: Whats it do when you try?  It works fine for me with no tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution (from [this blog post](http://hoang-tt.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/scroll-zoom-problem-in-ms-word.html)) worked for me:

> I am using Microsoft Mobile Mouse 6000 and the zoom function (by using CTRL + Scroll) did not work normally. What I did to overcome this problem is:
>
> - Open Control Panel -> Mouse
> - Select Wheel tab,  then select Identify programs that don't scroll correctly...  -> Click Add -> Browse for Microsoft Word -> Click OK -> OK.
> - Now, come back to Ms Word, it will work perfectly.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Word.

I suggest that you run Windows Update and look for any hardware updates as regarding the mouse.

If you are using IntelliPoint, get the [latest drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=mk).

If nothing helps, please add to your post your computer model, mouse model, Windows version and mouse software (if you have installed any).